# Set host globally for routes

Tags: symfony, routes

AFAIK Symfony2 is indifferent of the host in routing unless a host is specified.

I currently don't make use of subdomains in my app, but this is going to change. What I want, is that when a subdomain is present in the host (http://subdomain.foo.bar), the router only matches routes if the route configuration has a subdomain in the host.

**This should match:** (which it does)

```
/**
 * @Route("/", host="{subdomain}.%host%")
 * @Template
 */
public function index()
```

**This should not match and return 404:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template
 */
public function index()
```

Because of the aforementioned indifference, this route is also matched for http://subdomain.foo.bar

So what I want is to set the host requirement globally (foo.bar) and then specify for specific routes that they should also match when a subdomain is present.

I tried adding the host requirement to the import in `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
foo:
    resource: "@AcmeFooBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    host:     foo.bar
    prefix:   /
```

However, that host requirement "wins" from the ones specified in the annotation, resulting in no match for any of the two routes (mentioned above) when a subdomain is present in the actual host.

What does work is setting the host name globablly per controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(host="foo.bar")
 */
class bazController
```

But I'd much rather configure this somewhere globally.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a custom route compiler:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler as BaseRouteCompiler;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

class RouteCompiler extends BaseRouteCompiler
{
    public static function compile(Route $route)
    {
        if ($route->getHost() === "") {
            $route->setHost($route->getDefaults()['default_host']);
        }

        return parent::compile($route);
    }
}
```

Then in your routing file:

```
foo:
    resource: "@BarBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    options:
        compiler_class: Foo\Bundle\CoreBundle\Router\RouteCompiler
    defaults:
        default_host: %router.request_context.host%
```

Comment: how efficient is it to compile routes on every request.